# After installing Windows 10 LTSC on a separate intenal HD, the Linux portion of my "fdisk -l" output has a column it didn't have prior

Tags: linux, windows, fdisk

I have two harddrives in this computer—one is a regular SSD, the other is an M2 SSD. I installed Arch on the regular one and, after a little over a week of having it, installed Windows 10 LTSC on the M2 (gotta play my games, yo). Now the output of my `fdisk -l` looks like this:

```
Device     Boot    Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        2048    2099199    2097152    1G ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb2        2099200 1155532799 1153433600  550G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5        2101248   65015807   62914560   30G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6       65017856   98572287   33554432   16G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb7       98574336 1147150335 1048576000  500G 83 Linux
```

The `Id` column was *never* there prior to my installing Windows, and the windows portion of this output doesn't have this column:

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    923647    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   923648   1128447    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1128448   1161215     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1161216 488396799 487235584 232.3G Microsoft basic data
```

I've been reading a lot about [libreboot](https://libreboot.org/), so my curiosity is peaked. Did Windows, or maybe the installation of some drivers *in* Windows, do something deeper than just adding files to the M2 SSD to affect the way the Linux kernel sees the HD it's on?

(These two HDs are pretty separate, even having their own separate boot partitions. They don't interact with one another outside of me mounting the Windows partition in Linux [which I have yet to do!])

Comment: These IDs looks like standard partition type IDs to me. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_type

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh, they are. I don't think they IDs themselves are anything suspicious—I'm just wondering why that column showed up immediately after I installed Windows.

Comment: I'd be more interested in knowing why that column did _not_ show up for `/dev/sdb`.  I've never seen `fdisk -l` output without that column on Linux.